# Change input val and trigger its onkeyup

Tags: jquery, triggers, keyup, onkeyup

I want to auto change input's val and trigger its onkeyup event.

Error: e.which is undefined

```
<input type="text" id="x">
```

JS

```
$("#x").keyup(function(e){ console.debug(e.which); });
```

I tried

```
$("#x").val('m').keyup();
$("#x").val('m').trigger("keyup");
$("#x").val('m').trigger("keypress", [35]);
```

How can I change val and trigger just keyup function?
I need **e.which**.

Edit: if i write manuel to input, i can get debug result (which)

Comment: doe your input exist at the load of your page or is it loaded after ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: (just change the value of `letterToUse` each time)

```
var letterToUse = "A";

var e = $.Event("keyup");
e.which=e.keyCode=letterToUse.charCodeAt();
$("#x").val(letterToUse).trigger(e);
```